# How to take array elements as input

Tags: java, arrays

My program is to accept words (given as number of test cases) and print them out in reversed order. The problem is that whatever input of array size I may give, it only accepts just one word (and rest as blank). Can anyone help me figure out why? Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class terrible {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test = input.nextInt();
        while(test>0){
            String str = input.nextLine();char c[] = str.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
                System.out.print(c[str.length()-i-1]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            test--;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I executed your code. Let say I put 3 for the no of test cases then it accepts 2 cases. can u add some input and output?

Comment: for me, too. The problem when you type 3 and you can only type 2 is subscripe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. Executing it and providing the string "salut comment ça va" gave the output "av aç tnemmoc tulas". Indeed there is a bug when specifying the number of iteration (it iterates n-1 times) but is it your issue?

Comment: I added an input.nextLine() line after nextInt() to consume last newline character. It still seems to be taking just one string input irrespective of specified test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Certain versions of Java don't let you take an `int` and then a `string` as input from the same `Scanner`. You can create another `Scanner`, like

`Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);`

and then do

`String str = input2.nextLine();`